# CUDA compiler not optimizing multiply by zero for sm_20

Tags: optimization, compilation, cuda

I have the following (reduced test-case!) CUDA kernel

```
__global__
void test(int n, const double* __restrict__ in, double* __restrict__ out)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * threadIdx.x;

    if (idx < n)
    {
        out[idx] = 0.0*in[idx] + 1.0;
    }
}
```

which I would expect to generate code equivalent to `out[idx] = 1.0`.  (No-op expressions such as `0.0*in[idx]` arise when kernels are generated automatically using a template engine where the `0.0` started life as a `${template_parameter}`.)  However, `nvcc -arch sm_20 -ptx ...` generates:

```
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
// Compiler built on Sat Sep 22 01:35:14 2012 (1348274114)
// Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221
//

.version 3.1
.target sm_20
.address_size 64

[...]

    mul.wide.s32    %rd5, %r1, 8;
    add.s64     %rd6, %rd2, %rd5;
    ld.global.f64   %fd1, [%rd6];
    fma.rn.f64  %fd2, %fd1, 0d0000000000000000, 0d3FF0000000000000;
    add.s64     %rd7, %rd1, %rd5;
    st.global.f64   [%rd7], %fd2;
```

where there is a clear global load and FMA.  Yet when `-arch sm_10` is specified to nvcc it generates the expected code of `out[idx] = 1.0`.  Are there any compiler options/flags that can coax it into performing the aforementioned optimization?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on optimization with -O3 flag?

Comment: For the CC 2.0 compiler, NVIDIA switched from GCC to LLVM. Maybe that optimization is not in LLVM.

Comment: Firstly, that is only PTX, so it is still possible that the assembler eliminates the multiply by zero. But then again, eliminating the multiply isn't an optimisation anyway - a double precision FMAD and a double precision MUL instruction take exactly the same number of cycles on Fermi anyway....

Comment: @talonmies Eliminating the multiply paves the way to eliminating the load which reduces memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point multiplications by zero are not optimized out because CUDA generally adheres to IEEE-754 semantics. In particular, IEEE-754 specifies that +-0 * +-infinity = NaN, +-0 * NaN = NaN, and +0 * -0 = -0. Please refer to section "F.8.2 Expression transformations" of the C99 standard for this and other transformations of floating-point expressions.

Comment: Hence why I was wondering if there is a flag similar to the -ffast-math of GCC or the default of ICC to disable such semantics.

Comment: nvcc provides a flag -use_fast_math, but it affects single-precision computation only, and mainly affects operation substitutions, not the relaxation of IEEE-754 semantics, as far as I am aware. In general, IEEE-754 semantics provide useful properties that increase the robustness of floating-point computations. The CUDA math library (which currently is provided as a collection of inline functions in header files), relies on IEEE-754 semantics.